# IF-Statement Combination with mb_strlen doesn't work

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a form with following if-statement's but it doesn't work. 
The First verification "If empty" does work but not the second one with mb_strlen, why?

That's my PHP-Code:

```
elseif(empty($_POST['project_title']) OR 
(mb_strlen($_POST['project_title'], 'UTF-8') <= 3)){
echo "Please correct the Project Title";}
```

I don't get also any error. Do I have some Syntax mistakes in my Code?

Comment: try displaying the result of `mb_strlen($_POST['project_title'], 'UTF-8')`

Comment: *"IF-Statement Combination with strlen doesn't work"* - `strlen()` or `mb_strlen()`? Your title is a bit misleading as is what you state in the question itself.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your code works fine. This little test script I ran:

```
<?php

echo test_title( '' );
echo test_title( 'pdf' );
echo test_title( 'This one works' );

function test_title( $title ) {

   echo "testing '$title'. ";

   if( empty( $title ) ||
       mb_strlen( $title, 'UTF-8') <= 3
     ){
        return "Please correct the Project Title\n";
     }

   return "looks fine\n";
}
```

Will output the following:

```
testing ''. Please correct the Project Title
testing 'pdf'. Please correct the Project Title
testing 'This one works'. looks fine
```

Comment: Ok, I have to agree that the question of the OP is missing clues for us to help him, but, still in what is your answer replying the question ?

Comment: My answer is that strlen does indeed work, and that the 'if' statement they posted is correct. Her/his problem is not within the code that they suspect.

Comment: Dear CenterOrbit, thank you for your answer! 
After I changed elseif to "if" as you have done, it worked. 
I don't know actually why because before the elseif-condition I have another if-Condition. Whatever...it worked. ^^